# Using connectedness of $SL_n(R)$ How to show that $Gl_n(R)^+$ is connected?

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups

> Using connectedness of $SL_n(R)$ How to show that $Gl_n(R)^+$ is connected?

I can prove that Sl_n(R) is connected . How to prove using this fact only connectedness of all matrices with positive determinant ?

I wanted to solve this problem. Please give me hint.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $GL_n(\mathbb R)^+ = \mathbb R^+ \cdot SL_n(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Sir, Please check my answer: $A\in Gl_n(R)^+$ $A=xB$ where  $B\in Sl_n(R)$ Now there is path which take $x(0)=x,x(t)=1$ and As Sl_n(R) is connected we can path for B to Identity so together with there is path form A to Identity Hence Connected

Comment: That works if you assume that $SL_n(R)^+$ is path-connected. But connected and path-connected is not the same thing. Instead, you need a different argument. If you want a further hint, ask away.

Comment: @barto In case of manifold, Both connected and path-connected are same